# Backspace on Bing removes two characters

Tags: windows-8.1-preview, bing, internet-explorer-11

I am using Windows 8.1 with IE 11. Whenever I hit `backspace` in the [Bing](http://bing.com) search bar it removes two characters. This happens

- ONLY on the search bar (main page, top of search pages)
- NOT on any other textbox on Bing or anywhere else

I have no trouble with Bing on Firefox/Windows 8.1 or with IE 10/Windows 8.0.

What is wrong? How do I fix it?

Related questions on answers.microsoft.com:

- [IE11 and Typing in Bing.com's Search Bar, Backspace removes 2 characters](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/forum/bing_other-bing_users/ie11-and-typing-in-bingcoms-search-bar-backspace/28622192-0f88-4338-a628-8ca068fbda75) has more details from someone with the same problem and links to...
- [Bing Search Bar in IE11 Problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/forum/bing_websearch-bing_suggestions/bing-search-bar-in-ie11-problem/760b62e0-0c5c-4d06-a2e2-5a737971a2ca) has two people with more evidence and a non-answer

Comment: Did this happen with windows 8.0 and IE11?

Comment: @chipperyman573 No. It only happens in Windows 8.1/IE 11 and only on the Bing search bar. I cannot get it to happen anywhere else.

Comment: What are your regional settings? Have you changed these recently? Do you have more than one keyboard installed?

Comment: @RandolphWest I have not changed my regional settings (EDT, en-us), and I have only one keyboard, a Microsoft Sidewinder X4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put bing.com in compatibility view settings, this solved the issue for me with bing.com in IE11.

1. Go to bing.com
2. Hit the <kbd>alt</kbd> key
3. Select `Tools`
4. Select `Compatibility View settings`
5. Click `Add`

Comment: This worked. My concern is that Microsoft will finally fix Bing and then I'll still be using compatibility mode. But then again, I'll be upgrading to full 8.1 when it comes out, so I guess this is a non-issue. Thanks Do Kim!